Plural of acronym ending in Latin word
In scientific writing we often use acronyms to try to improve readability of the text. Normally an acronym is pluralised with an s (lower case) at the end, such as ATMs. However, some of the words in the acronyms I use have a Latin root, for example 'nucleus', plural 'nuclei'. If such a word is at the end of an acronym, what is the correct plural?
For the (fictitious) acronym of Growth Nucleus (GN), would the plural be 'GNs'?

As someone who has written several scientific papers, I have never had any peer-review people tell me that they had more of a problem with the usage of acronym plurals like "GMWDs" than with the actual content of the paper. Just don't use apostrophes when you don't have to is my two cents.

The Chicago Manual of Style (CMOS) differentiates (10.2) between acronyms (abbreviations read as a single word, like AIDS or laser) and initialism (abbreviations read as a series of letters, like IRS or NBA). GN would be an initalism, not an acronym.
Abbreviations usually form the plural by adding s (7.15). There are some exceptions, such as SI units (10.53), for which the same symbols are used for singular and plural, e.g. 1 m (one meter) and 3 m (three meters), or US measures (10.65), e.g. 10 yd. (ten yards). But these execptions from the plural-s rule are all well-established conventions. Your case doesn't fall under them.
Latin sometimes forms the plural of abbreviations by doubling the last letter, e.g. AVGG NN for Augusti nostri "our Augustuses" (referring to three emperors with the same name) or, more well-known today, pp. for paginae "pages" (CMOS 10.42). But again, your case doesn't fall under them, because yours is an English phrase, even if one word was loaned from Latin.
So, I would say that your abbreviation should follow the general rule and form its plural with s as GNs.

See also this answer to a very similar question, which emphasises

that you should treat the initialism as its own entity, apart from the words it represents. As the Chicago Manual says:

If you can stop thinking of the spelled-out meaning of the acronym and just treat the acronym itself as a word with its own meaning, you should be able to add that little s without fretting.
.


